# Web Deployment Visual Studio2013 IIS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, iis-8.5

I almost figured out how to break this mystery of IIS Publishing, but I have't been able to do so yet. I think this time is the setting output in Visual Studio.
No error code or anything and I just need to get it run.

Here is the snapshot of local host output.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried browsing to `localhost\Default.aspx` ?

Comment: blank html output without any design on background. In fact I also had to manually configure aspx extension. added as MIME type in IIS manager

Comment: Reinstalling Visual Studio. There is probably something wrong with ASP.net  framework.